# How can I cheat program that stdin is terminal (and not redirected file)?

Tags: bash, terminal, stdin

I am doing standard redirection:

```
$ cat file.txt | /usr/bin/program
```

But the program behaves differently if I run it directly in terminal and copy-paste input.
It displays a progress bar when the input is a terminal. I would like to have the progress bar anyway.

In short, how can I "cheat" the program that the input comes from the terminal and is not redirected from a file?

Comment: `/usr/bin/program file.txt` doesn't work?

Comment: Or `/usr/bin/program < file.txt`?

Comment: The traditional approach is to use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 5):

It may be simplest to use the [`expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/) program; it does most of the necessary work for you.

The necessary work is fiddly.  It involves using pseudo-ttys, which are devices that look to programs like terminals.  If you're going to roll your own, then the POSIX system calls you need to know about are:

- [`posix_openpt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_openpt.html)
- [`ptsname()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ptsname.html)
- [`granpt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/grantpt.html)
- [`unlockpt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlockpt.html)

The `posix_openpt()` interface is relatively new (Issue 6, compared with Issue 4, Version 2 for the other functions listed). If your system doesn't have `posix_openpt()`, you need to get yourself one of the Unix books (Stevens or Rochkind, probably) to find out how else to do open the master side of a pty, or read your system manuals rather carefully.  However, the rationale for `posix_openpt()` at the link above may also help — it also has guidelines for using the other functions.  Linux has `posix_openpt()`; so does Mac OS X and by inference the BSD systems generally.

Books:

- W Richard Stevens, Stephen A Rago
  [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739)
- Marc J Rochkind
  [Advanced Unix Programming, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543)

Comment: What if the program which should produce colorized output is in the middle of a shell pipe? I assume it doesn't matter whether its called by expect or not

Comment: @hek2mgl: If the program is in the middle of a pipeline, it will probably not produce colour output by default, but there may be an option to force it to do colouring automatically (probably with a misspelled option such as `--color=force`).

Comment: You were too fast :) I was about to correct "in the middle" by "at the end" .. (as in the middle makes no sense here)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Sorry about being too responsive :D … At the end of a pipeline, normally the command will detect whether its output is a 'terminal' and if so, it will consider colouring the output.  There might be an option to force it to colour it; there may be no way to influence it when it makes the 'wrong' decision.

Comment: However, it's late here. Thanks for the fast response :) btw, good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a pseudo-tty to have the effect you desire. 'man pty' will tell you more about it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the program will call the glibc function `isatty()` to check whether stdin/stdout is a terminal or not. That's common for programs which use colorized output on terminals or other features of an ANSI terminal like cursor positioning or line erasing / redrawing.

You can trick the program using the LD_PRELOAD environment variable. LD_PRELOAD is handled by the ELF linker and tells that a dynamic library should be loaded **before** all others. Using this feature it is possible to override library functions, in your case the glibc function `isatty()`.

Here comes an example:

*libisatty.c*

```
/**
 * Overrides the glibc function. Will always return true.
 *
 * Note: Although this should be ok for most applications it can
 * lead to unwanted side effects. It depends on the question
 * why the programm calls isatty()
 */
int isatty(int param) {
    return 1;
}
```

*Makefile*

```
# Make the shared Library
lib: libisatty.c
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libisatty.so.1 -o libisatty.so.1.0  libisatty.c 
    ln -s libisatty.so.1.0 libisatty.so.1
    ln -s libisatty.so.1 libisatty.so
```

Run:

```
make lib
```

It should build fine, I've tested it on Ubuntu12.04 AMD 64.

Now it's time to test the library. :) I've used the command `ls --color=auto` for tests. `ls` calls `isatty()` to decide whether it should colorize it's output or not. If the output is redirected to a file or a pipe it won't be colorized. You can test this easily using the following commands:

```
ls --color=auto        # should give you colorized output
ls --color=auto | cat  # will give you monochrome output
```

Now we'll try the second command again using the LD_PRELOAD environment var:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libisatty.so ls --color=auto | cat
```

You should see colorized output.